# Do we need a static IP to use HTML5 Websockets?

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am in the process of building a chat application in PHP using Web Sockets. I started with the code [phpwebsocket project](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)  and [here](http://blog.ilric.org/2011/02/14/super-simple-chat-using-websockets/). The code works fine on my local machine but when i try it on my site (does not have a dedicated IP) it has a problem establishing the web socket connection. I tried it with all possible combinations for socket binding (site addres, external ip addr, local ip addr) but failed.

Comment: I have a suspicion this is a networking problem rather than programming related. Have you tried basic connectivity tests? Are you trying to go through a firewall?

Comment: I have disabled my firewall. Also when i try running the socket server from another pc in my LAN and connect to using local IP addr it works fine.

Comment: What happens if you try to telnet to the port number on the server for the site? Do you have shell access to the server?

Comment: No I am not able to telnet to mysite on the port i have specified for binding web socket. yea i have shell access, that s how i running the php websocket script on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be able to connect to the port on the server where the WebSocket server is running. If you are using a port other than 80 or 443 on your site for the WebSocket server, then you probably need to configure (or ask) the site to accept incoming connections on that port (because they may deny it by default for security reasons). It you are unable to telnet to the WebSocket port on the server, then this is likely the case (or phpwebsocket is not in fact correctly configured to list on that port).